# What is the best method for Replacement of MapToStoredProcedures() in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have implemented the project of EntityFramework 6 into EntityFramework Core 3.1.
Using Roslyn API, I have to do migrate the Properties, Types, and Methods of Entity framework. Now I have struck with MapToStoredProcedures

**Sample.cs**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(sp => sp.HasName("sp_InsertStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name").Result(rs => rs.StudentId, "Id"))
                    .Update(sp => sp.HasName("sp_UpdateStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name"))
                    .Delete(sp => sp.HasName("sp_DeleteStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentId, "Id"))
            );
}
```

Based on the link https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/245. there is no more supported in EF Core and also most of the stack overflow links are suggested by the DbContext method. I have no idea about this.

Kindly suggest an alternative solution on this and how to do it in Roslyn API?

Comment: How does this relate to Roslyn?

Comment: This is not possible in EFCore yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no replacement. Use standard EF Core Save changes.

Comment: then entire structure has to be changed  if we migrate EF to EF Core regarding StoredProcedure ,right?

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ, What about FromSql method, ?

Comment: FromSQL is for SELECT, you can use ExecuteSqlRaw for CUD

Comment: Thank you@ErikEJ

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ, Do you have any idea about replacement of Map() in EF Core